# Seagate Backup Plus Portable software throws an exception

Tags: hard-drive

I bought a Seagate Backup Plus Portable 5TB drive. It comes with a Seagate Toolkit. But when I run it, it throws an exception. I'm using Windows 10.

I have attempted to paste the exception but I don't see how.

Does anyone have any information that may help to get it running?

Eddy

Comment: Go here with your backup serial number and download the Windows 10 software. Try that. https://www.seagate.com/ca/en/support/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/backup-plus/#downloads

Comment: Uninstall the old version before installing the new one.

Comment: I cannot edit my comment. I should have noted I have this backup device running on Windows 10 Pro machine in a not-for-profit client

Comment: That is the one I was trying to load. I downloaded it anyway and it gives the same problem.

Comment: There should be a Seagate log somewhere with clues to the issue.